# The extension of Riemann map to a homeomorphism of neighborhoods of domains

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a nonempty simply connected domain, which is not all of $\mathbb{C}$ and has locally connected boundary, then the Riemann map $\phi:\mathbb D\to U$ can be extended continuously to the boundary.

My question is whether we can extend $\phi$ to be a homeomorphism $\overline\phi:N(\overline{\mathbb D})\to N(\overline{U})$, where $N(\overline{\mathbb D})$ and $N(\overline{U})$ are some neighborhoods of $\overline{\mathbb D}$ and $\overline{U}$, respectively. Any suggestions?

Comment: No. Let $U$ be the slit unit disc. Then (essentially because the inverse Riemann map has a square root in it) the extension $\overline{\Bbb D} \to \overline U$ fails to be injective.

Answer (score 2):

Forget neighborhoods for the moment: to have a homeomorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ onto $\overline{U}$, you need the boundaries of these sets to be homeomorphic. Thus, it is necessary to assume that $\partial U$ is a Jordan curve.

Thanks to [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)) this   condition is also sufficient for the conformal map to extend to a homeomorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ onto $\overline{U}$.

Once you have that, the [Jordan-Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem) assures an extension of this homeomorphism to a global homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$.